# python script not creating log file on DigitalOcean server

Tags: python, logging, digital-ocean

My python script runs fine on my local computer and creates log file too. Here is the logging configuration

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(threadName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO, filename='my_alerts.log')
```

But when I upload the script to digitalocean ubuntu server, it runs fine but doesn't create any `log` file.

what could be wrong?

Here are the permissions to the folder:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked permission?

Comment: 777.. all permissions given. does the owner/group matters?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I need to give full path to the .log file in loggin.config() statement because I am running the python script as a service.

Comment: Hi, can you please answer my question? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72853006/python-log-files-are-not-generating-on-digital-ocean-app-platform)