# Python log files are not generating on Digital Ocean app platform

Tags: python, logging, digital-ocean

I have deployed a python Flask application on Digital Ocean's app platform. My app implements python's `logging` module to create logs. While it works fine on the local system. the logs are not being generated on the Digital Ocean server. I have mentioned the log path as `LOG_LOCATION = './logs/'` in my `config.py` file. Whereas the directory structure is -

```
|- app
  |- __init__.py
  |- config.py
  |- ...
|- logs
|- ...
```

Reading from one of the sources, I found a suggestion to provide the complete path instead of relative ones. I tried it (shown below) but it did not work.

- Digital Ocean console

```
apps@myflaskapp:~/logs$ pwd
/workspace/logs
```

- Modification done in `config.py`

```py
LOG_LOCATION = '/workspace/logs'
```

Comment: Just in case - having run into this myself it turned out that I had added the files to the .gitignore so weren't making it to DigitalOcean.

Regarding relative paths, I've found using the pathlib module helpful:

`basedir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent`